# split string into different parts without spaces and dividers

Tags: c, string, split, scanf

I have a string 2020122812.txt which I want to be able to extract for numbers from which are a four digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day and 2 digit hour.

Below is a snippet of my code in which I had attempted to do this where 2020122812.txt would be entered as the first argument:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char txtfName[500];
     int bYYYY;
     int bMM;
     int bDD;
     int bHH;

     sprintf(txtName,"%s",argv[1]);
     sscanf(txtName,"%.4d%.2d%0.2d%0.2d.txt",YYYY,MM,DD,HH);
     printf("YYYY=%d\n",YYYY);
     printf("MM=%d\n",MM);
     printf("DD=%d\n",DD);
     printf("HH=%d\n",HH);
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting zeros for YYYY, MM, DD, HH instead of the desired results of:

```
  2020 for YYYY
  12 for MM
  28 for DD
  12 for HH.
```

How do I tweak this code to get my desired results?

Comment: `YYYY`, `MM`, `DD`, and `HH` are undeclared here. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also it is suspicious that same things are passed to `scanf()` and `printf()` for dealing with integers. One more note is that it may be better to use `argv[1]` directly for `sscanf()` instead of copying just for creating risk of buffer overun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `printf()`, conversion specifiers in `scanf()` don't have options to specify precision. The maximum length to read should be specified without `.`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int YYYY;
     int MM;
     int DD;
     int HH;

     if (argc < 2) return 1;

     if (sscanf(argv[1],"%4d%2d%2d%2d.txt",&YYYY,&MM,&DD,&HH) != 4) return 1;
     printf("YYYY=%d\n",YYYY);
     printf("MM=%d\n",MM);
     printf("DD=%d\n",DD);
     printf("HH=%d\n",HH);
}
```

Also these errors are fixed in this code:

- Required header was not included.
- The number of argument(s) was not checked.
- The result of `sscanf()` was not checked.
- Undeclared identifiers were used.
- `&` was missing in the arguments of `sscanf()`.
- The input was copied just for creating risk of buffer overrun.